# By using import.socket, is there a way to retrieve DHCP ip instead? or do I have to minus one from the IP?

Tags: python, sockets, dhcp

As per title, I would like to retrieve the DHCP IP of the units I connect.

So far I have:

```
import socket

def getIPAddresses():
    addr = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
    for i in addr[2]:
        if "169.254" in i:
            if i != "169.254.0.2":
                print socket.gethostbyaddr(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    getIPAddresses()
```

Essentially, the scenario is that I have two units connected where I want to connect to the unit whose IP is not 169.254.0.1.

I guess it would also be nice if there is a more efficient way to write this but my main concern would be to retrieve the DHCP IP of the IP instead (where DHCP IP is minus 1)

this would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: is there a way you can get the IP address for the MAC address of the machine you are trying to connect to?

Comment: yes, though I haven't looked how using socket import

Comment: with DHCP this should be a more reliable solution for you.

Comment: yes. but i won't do it for you ;) this will help
https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=python+query+arp+table

Comment: you need to query the arp table. the arp table holds the information that you need.

Comment: i guess i wont pretend to say that I understand any of those entries in google, but thanks for trying to help anyways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301318/what-does-arp-do

Comment: thanks paul! actually just ended up using another function due to modules not being properly supported by what I was using. But went with my secondary way where I just split, subtracted by one, then joined it up. i know not efficient but it worked the way i wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix, I just subtracted one by the last section of the IP.

```
ip_oct = ip.split('.')
ip_oct[3] = str(int(ip_oct[3]) -1)
return '.'.join(ip_oct)
```

I'm sure its not the most elegant solution but this brought the number lines down substantially and made it simplified imo

I'm basically splitting the IP I retrieve. then with the last set, I subtract one. I then join them up with . to return back to IP.

Just to toss it out there, I had no luck using getting `gethostbyname_ex` to work via Google Robot Framework so I had to use `getaddrinfo` to retrieve the IP.

Again, not the optimal solution as I would like to do it through MAC addresses and ARP but ... I had no time to figure it out and will get back to it in a few months